# button with 2 images and text in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a button with two images on it. One at left side and one at right side and text in center. After searching I got a button with image only so I wanted to know if it is posible to create a button as I described above in xamarin?

I am trying to create button like this and also I want to change arrow image on the button click to up arrow and down arrow. Is it posible in xamarin to create button like this or should I think about another option any idea?

[image]

Comment: Native Xamarin or Forms?

Comment: From within the X.F project you can max do is use a layout like `StackLayout` and make it look like a button with images. Or else you can create the custom renders in the specific native projects and implement it.

Comment: acually this is not simple button..this is accordian button.which exand data below it from code.that accordian code i dont done.so i dont know how to replace that button with stack layout..so can u give some suggestion in button how to customise it?

Comment: i think i m confusing you. see, i have created demo from this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088093/Simple-Accordion-User-Control-in-Xamarin-Forms in which there is simple button.so can i replce that to stack layout as u said???

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this with the Button from Xamarin Forms as it doesn't support images yet.

From your requirement what you can do is create a horizontal stacklayout and add the images and a label to it. Also set a background color so that it would look like a button. 
To make it work like a button, add a Gesture recognizer to the stack layout and add the tap gesture. 
You can handle the event for tapping or bind it via command if you are using MVVM.