# How to get a second picture on the button in a Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am writing a button custom renderer for my Xamarin app. Therefore I inherit from the class ButtonRenderer and use the Control to customize my button. I need two images in this button, on the left and on the right. In the middle there is a text label. How do I get a second image in the button in the C#-Class (not in xaml)

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991845/button-with-2-images-and-text-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: it would be much easier to do this by creating a custom control in forms with a layout container and a gesture recognizer

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method to add images to the top, bottom, left and right of the `Button` for Android .

```
class MyButtonRenderer :ButtonRenderer
{
    public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control !=null)
        {
            Control.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.fivePlus), null, Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.fivePlus), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get: 'UIButton' does not contain a definition for 'SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds' and no accessible extension method 'SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds' accepting a first argument of type 'UIButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh, so your solution is just for Android? Do you have an idea how to solve this in Xamarin for iOS?

Comment: @M_B For ios,the UIButton has no ready-made way to set up images around you like Android does.You should custom a control,something like a label with two uiimage.